# Difference between `(Integer a) => a -> Bool` and ` Integer -> Bool`?

Tags: function, haskell, purely-functional

I wrote my first program in Haskell today. [It compiles and runs successfully](http://ideone.com/hkvFz). And since it is not a typical *"Hello World"* program, it in fact does much more than that, so please congrats me :D

Anyway, I've few doubts regarding my code, and the syntax in Haskell.

**Problem:**

My program reads an integer `N` from the standard input and then, for each integer `i` in the range `[1,N]`, it prints whether `i` is a prime number or not. Currently it doesn't check for input error. :-)

**Solution:** (also doubts/questions)

To solve the problem, I wrote this function to test primality of an integer:

```
is_prime :: Integer -> Bool
is_prime n = helper n 2
        where
          helper :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
          helper n i  
              | n < 2 * i = True
              | mod n i > 0 = helper n (i+1)
              | otherwise = False
```

It works great. But my doubt is that the first line is a result of many hit-and-trials, as what I read in [this tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) didn't work, and gave this error (I *suppose* this is an error, though it doesn't say so):

```
prime.hs:9:13:
    Type constructor `Integer' used as a class
    In the type signature for `is_prime':
      is_prime :: Integer a => a -> Bool
```

According to [the tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) (which is a nicely-written tutorial, by the way), the first line should be: (*the tutorial says `(Integral a) => a -> String`, so I thought `(Integer a) => a -> Bool` should work as well.*)

```
is_prime :: (Integer a) => a -> Bool
```

which doesn't work, and gives the above posted error (?).

And why does it not work?  What is the difference between this line (which doesn't work) and the line (which works)?

---

Also, what is the idiomatic way to loop through `1` to `N`? I'm not completely satisfied with the loop in my code. Please suggest improvements. Here is my code:

```
--read_int function
read_int :: IO Integer
read_int = do
     line <- getLine
     readIO line

--is_prime function
is_prime :: Integer -> Bool
is_prime n = helper n 2
        where
          helper :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
          helper n i  
              | n < 2 * i = True
              | mod n i > 0 = helper n (i+1)
              | otherwise = False

main = do
       n <- read_int
       dump 1 n
       where
           dump i x = do 
                 putStrLn ( show (i) ++ " is a prime? " ++ show (is_prime i) )
                 if i >= x 
                    then putStrLn ("")
                  else do
                    dump (i+1) x
```

Comment: Do you mean `Integral a`?

Comment: @Heatsink: No. I don't even know if `Integral` exists. Does it? Is it supposed to be `Integral`?

Comment: It probably is supposed to be `Integral`.  Also, your two hyperlinks go to the same URL, is that intentional?

Comment: @Heatsink: Hyperlinks are corrected.

Comment: Just a few things not strictly related to the problem you're having: function application in Haskell is just juxtaposition, so `show (i)` = `show i`, `putStrLn ("")` = `putStrLn ""`; dominant naming convention is camelCase (basically all libraries use it) and `read_int` is already in `Prelude` under the name `readLn`.

Comment: @Vitus: `readLn` reads an integer? or any line, including Strings? How to use it to read integers?

Comment: It basically reads anything that has `Read` instance. Try `:i Read` in GHCi; there's ton of instances. The actual type you want to read is usually determined by context (which would be `Integer` in your case); you can also specify the type manually: `readLn :: IO Integer`.

Comment: The tutorial says `(Integral a) =>`. There's no such thing as `(Integer a) =>`, it will not compile.

Comment: @n.m.: The tutorial says `(Integral a) => a -> String`, so I thought `(Integer a) => a -> Bool` should work as well.

Comment: `Integral` is not a type (it's a type class), on the other hand `Integer` is. I suggest you to just skip it, the tutorial will get back to type classes in few chapters and that should make it clear. (edit: it is actually one chapter before, sorry!)

Comment: @Nawaz `Integral` is explained in the same tutorial near the end of "Typeclasses 101": http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101  Please read it again and try to narrow your question more, so we can understand where the confusion comes from.  I can't tell whether you would be helped by an explanation of the difference between types and typeclasses, how numbers are overloaded, or something else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are misreading the tutorial. It would say the type signature should be

```
is_prime :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
--       NOT Integer a
```

These are different types:

- `Integer -> Bool`

  - This is a function that takes a value of type `Integer` and gives back a value of type `Bool`.
- `Integral a => a -> Bool`

  - This is a function that takes a value of type `a` and gives back a value of type `Bool`.
  - What is `a`? It can be any type of the caller's choice that implements the `Integral` type class, such as `Integer` or `Int`.

(And the difference between `Int` and `Integer`? The latter can represent an integer of any magnitude, the former wraps around eventually, similar to `int`s in C/Java/etc.)

---

The idiomatic way to loop depends on what your loop does: it will either be a map, a fold, or a filter.

Your loop in `main` is a map, and because you're doing i/o in your loop, you need to use `mapM_`.

```
let dump i = putStrLn ( show (i) ++ " is a prime? " ++ show (is_prime i) )
 in mapM_ dump [1..n]
```

Meanwhile, your loop in `is_prime` is a fold (specifically `all` in this case):

```
is_prime :: Integer -> Bool
is_prime n = all nondivisor [2 .. n `div` 2]
        where
          nondivisor :: Integer -> Bool
          nondivisor i = mod n i > 0
```

(And on a minor point of style, it's conventional in Haskell to use names like `isPrime` instead of names like `is_prime`.)

Comment: Nitpick: `coprime` is a misleading name. It turns out that it is actually only called for `i` where the result corresponds to the name, but without short-circuiting, `is_prime 18` would call `coprime 8` which then would evaluate to `True` although 8 and 18 aren't coprime. Call it `nondivisor` or so.

Comment: @dave4420: I didn't understand your definition of `is_prime` . What is `i` in `[2 .. i \`div\` 2]`? How does its initial value get decided? How does it get incremented? And upto what value?

Comment: Ohh.. I think you meant `n` instead of `i` (in the list)?

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, sorry, that's exactly what I meant, I just typed it in wrong. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

**Part 1:** If you look at the tutorial again, you'll notice that it actually gives type signatures in the following forms:

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
-- or
isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool -- equivalent
```

Here, `Integer` is the name of a concrete type (has an actual representation) and `Integral` is the name of a class of types.  The `Integer` type is a member of the `Integral` class.

The constraint `Integral a` means that whatever type `a` happens to be, `a` has to be a member of the `Integral` class.

**Part 2:** There are plenty of ways to write such a function.  Your recursive definition looks fine (although you might want to use `n < i * i` instead of `n < 2 * i`, since it's faster).

If you're learning Haskell, you'll probably want to try writing it using higher-order functions or list comprehensions.  Something like:

```
module Main (main) where
import Control.Monad (forM_)

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n = all (\i -> (n `rem` i) /= 0) $ takeWhile (\i -> i^2 <= n) [2..]

main :: IO ()
main = do n <- readLn
          forM_ [1..n] $ \i ->
              putStrLn (show (i) ++ " is a prime? " ++ show (isPrime i))
```

Comment: @Vitus: Ohh I need to import that. I've not come across `import` yet. [thanks :-)](http://ideone.com/iNCAI)

Comment: Btw, what does this syntax `\i -> (n \`rem\` i) /= 0` mean?

Comment: `\i ->` introduces an anonymous function taking one argument (named `i` inside function body). `n \`rem\` i` is just another way of writing `rem n i`. You can turn any function into infix operator by surrounding it in backticks.

Comment: @Vitus: And this *anonymous function* is more like *lambda* which *captures* local variables, such as `n`, right?

Comment: It's basically as if you declared a local function inside `where` clause. And yes, it captures its context - that is, all free variables.

Answer (score 3):

1. It is `Integral a`, not `Integer a`. See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers.
2. `map` and friends is how you loop in Haskell. This is how I would re-write the loop:

   ```
   main :: IO ()
   main = do
           n <- read_int
           mapM_ tell_prime [1..n]
           where tell_prime i = putStrLn (show i ++ " is a prime? " ++ show (is_prime i))
   ```